# iPad App with Multiple PopOvers

Tags: uitableview, ipad, uipopovercontroller, popover

More of a "best practice" question with regards to good application design. I have an application that has a number of popover controllers, each with different content. My first instinct was to create a new TableViewController for the content of each popover.

Is this the best way to go about things? I was wondering if it was possible or more tidy to handle the display of all this content within one TableViewController, and present different arrays of content depending on the popover?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your delegate/data source code is very similar between all tables I would recommend keeping the classes apart.  It will make your code more modifiable in the future if you want to sub-split out one of these views or add additional popovers.